# ruby on rails class inside self class passing the get the instant variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

```
class A
    def initialize(x)
        @x = x
    end
    class << self
        def abcd
            puts @x
            puts 'something..'
        end
    end
end
x = A.new('123')
x.abcd
```

here i need to get print the @x inside the abcd method.

in advance thanks.

Comment: `x.abcd` – looks like you want an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: `x.instance_variable_get(:@x) #=> "123"`. See [Object#instance_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get). `abcd` is a class method so it is invoked `A.abcd`, but that will not give you the value of the instance variable `@x`; rather, it will give you the value of the *class instance variable* `@x`, which is undefined. Confusing, I know. Suppose you added a line `@x = 'cat'` after `class A`. When that is executed `self` equals `A`. Then `A.abcd #=> 'cat'`. The instance variable `@x` and the class instance variable `@x` are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a class method that needs to be called on the class like `A.abcd`. But you initialize `@x` on an instance of `A` and also call an instance method by calling `x.abcd`.

Just remove the `class << self` from the class method definition

```
class << self
  def abcd
    puts @x
    puts 'something..'
  end
end
```

and change it to

```
def abcd
  puts @x
  puts 'something..'
end
```

Btw it is common in Ruby to indent code by just two whitespaces instead of four.